# Get Selected Tab View (iOS)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, tabs

First of all, and for your info, i am very new in iOS 6 programming but with strong background in PHP. So I know it is very different on both.

My question is, I want to try find out the code that can trigger 'if else' statement under one instance method in viewController after one tab is selected.

I am very appreciated for detailed answer and sorry if my question is too basic, because i am still new in ios. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller where you want this "if else" statement needs to be the delegate of the tab bar, and implement tabBar:didSelectItem:.

Comment: okey thanks for reply. are you meant on the viewController (where if else situated) needs to call the appdelegate and then implement tabBar:didSelectItem: at viewController?

Comment: @user1986121  No, this has nothing to do with the app delegate. The view controller needs to set itself as the delegate of the tab bar. It would help if you explained your project more fully. Are you using a stand-alone tab bar, or are you using a tab bar controller?

Comment: i am using tab bar controller..  it is quite unclear actually because i am working with other people codes but i will try to explain: I'm want to change variable with condition,means the variable is mutable depends on condition. The change will triggered after tapped on every tabs shown. Sorry if the explanation looks confusing. i am very appreciated with your help.